# Disable Touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

It is my understanding that I can disable my touchscreen by adding Option "Ignore" "on" to this file

```
          /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf

 Section "InputClass"
          Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
          MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
          MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
          Driver "evdev"
          EndSection
```

so it would look like this

```
 Section "InputClass"
          Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
          MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
          MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
          Driver "evdev"
          Option "Ignore" "on"
          EndSection
```

What would happen if I simplied changed MatchIsTouchscreen to "off"?

```
 Section "InputClass"
          Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
          MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
          MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
          Driver "evdev"
          EndSection
```

Would this disable my touchscreen?

Comment: I disable my touchscreen by `xinput --disable 'ELAN Touchscreen'`, having identified my touchscreen in `xinput -list`

Comment: i currently use xinput on start up, this is not the answer i am looking for.  My question is. What would happen if I simply changed MatchIsTouchscreen to "off"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited file the file with

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

Changed MatchIsTouchscreen from "on" to "off"

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        EndSection
```

"ELAN touchscreen" is disabled and no longer detected in xinput list.

Comment: ---- CAVEAT ---- Doing this on my ASUS made my mouse and keyboard stop working. I then had to edit the `10-evdev.conf` file using the VERY LIMITED onscreen keyboard (no arrow keys or ctrl key). Before trying this solution, first attempt to add the `Option "Ignore" "on"` line (worked for me). 

If you add the "off" line and it breaks your keyboard run the following via onscreen keyboard to fix your laptop: `sudo su && cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ && mv 10-evdev.conf evdevold && sed 's/"off"/"on"/g' evdevold > 10-evdev.conf && reboot`. Open this on your phone so you have it handy if needed.