# How do I disable the touchscreen on my Dell Precision 5560?

Tags: dell, touchscreen, input

**Summarize the problem**
I don't like my touchscreen, and attempts at [disabling it via `xinput`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers?newreg=7fd188641ef6490387fa808f5014767e) have proved fruitless.

**Provide details and any research**
I also tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923911/disable-touchscreen), but even after adding `Option "Ignore" "on"` to every single section that had "touchscreen" in the name, the touchscreen still worked.

**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**
As mentioned, neither xinput nor editing the configuration files worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the best solution was quite simple! I was able to turn it off in the Dell BIOS. I would encourage users of any brand of laptop to attempt to try it that way first. Zero hackiness!